# get date from timestamp

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

My code is:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String valueFromDB = "2012/06/06 00:00:00";

        String valueFromDB = "2012-12-31 00:00:00.0";
        Date d = new Date(valueFromDB);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String dateWithoutTime = sdf.format(d);

        System.out.println("sdf.format(d) " + dateWithoutTime);

    }
}
```

It works for `"2012/06/06 00:00:00"` and I need to pass `"2012-12-31 00:00:00.0"` it is showing illegal argument. May be because I have use `"-"` in date or because of timestamp fraction second. I need date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
String valueFromDB = "2012-12-31 00:00:00.0";
Date d1 = sdf1.parse(valueFromDB);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateWithoutTime = sdf.format(d1);
System.out.println("sdf.format(d) " + dateWithoutTime);
```

Comment: thnks juniad for the solution but i want to understand the code can you explain.

Comment: First parsing the String to a Date. In the process letting it know which format you are getting it in. The passing the date object to a formatter which formats it to the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful.

```
long dateTimeStamp = 1487269800;
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(dateTimeStamp*1000);
Date changeDate = new Date(stamp.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Date :Fri Feb 17 00:00:00 IST 2017
```

Comment: explain clearly that how your answer is related to the question. the answer you provided doesn't seem sufficiently descriptive!

Comment: see the time-stamp is fetched from db in long and now converted to milliseconds and its created in java timestamp which is used to get the date by calling the constructor of Date...............

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse a string to Date type, use the code below:

```
DateFormat formatter;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
date = (Date)formatter.parse("2012-12-31 00:00:00");
```

Comment: to parse the String with fraction seconds you should add a .S to the format: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S`